# How is the generator used in Feldman's Verifiable Secret Sharing scheme determined?

Tags: secret-sharing, group-theory

According to the Wikipedia description of [Feldman's VSS scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_secret_sharing)

> First, a cyclic group **G** of prime order **p**, along with a generator **g** of **G**, is chosen publicly as a system parameter. (Typically, one takes a subgroup of **(Z<sub>q</sub>)<sup>*</sup>**, where **q** is a prime such that **p** divides **q-1**.)

Why is it necessary to use a generator **g** in this process?
What is the procedure to be followed to implement a method which produces this generator for a given prime order group **Z<sub>p</sub>**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplicative group $\mathbf{Z}_p^*$ of non-zero integers modulo $p$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, so it has exactly one subgroup of order $k$ for each divisor $k$ of $p-1$.

To obtain an element $g$ of $G$, take any element $a$ of $\mathbf{Z}_p^*$ and let $g = a^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$. Then $g$ is an element of $G$ because
$$g^q = \left(a^{(p-1)/q}\right)^q = a^{p-1} = 1 \pmod p.$$

The order of $g$ is a divisor of the order of $G$, so it is a divisor of $q$, and since $q$ is prime, it equals either $1$ or $q$.